# Understanding how Python imports modules from a subdirectory while using VS-Code

Tags: python, python-import, visual-studio-code, pythonpath

Consider the following directory structure with the following contents:

```
my-project
├── main.py
├── lib
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── foo.py
│   └── bar.py
```

main.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append("./lib")

from foo import hello_world

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello_world()
```

foo.py

```
from lib.bar import name

def hello_world():
    print(f"Hello {name}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello_world()
```

bar.py

```
name = "Grogu"
```

When I run main.py, I run into no errors and I get what I expect: `Hello Grogu`. However, when I run lib/foo.py, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my-project/lib/foo.py", line 1, in <module>
    from lib.bar import name
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'
```

If I change `lib.bar` into `bar`, it works as expected, but I don't understand why VSCode doesn't seem to know what the lib folder is.

I'm using VSCode and I think there's something I'm doing wrong. My friend who uses pyCharm is able to run lib/foo.py just fine. It might have to be how VSCode and Pycharm interpret the source. Does anyone have any tips?

Basically I'm trying to import functions from a subdirectory and also preserve the ability to run individual files within the subdirectory, but I can't seem to find the proper way to do this in VScode.

Comment: Generally speaking you can't run individual files within the subdirectory of a Python package (if they try to `import` other scripts in the package).

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/python_imports.html

Answer (score -1):

When you execute a Python script, the specific directory where the script is located is added to the path, but not its parent's directory.

So, when you run `python foo.py` from inside lib the path will contain `.../my-project/lib` but not `.../my-project`, and therefore Python cannot find the module `lib`. However, it works with `bar` because the file does exist in `.../my-project/lib`.

To be able to run from both the root dir and lib, you can insert/append the parent directory (i.e. the root dir) to the path in the lib `__init__.py`:

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

sys.path.insert(0, str(Path(__file__).parent))
```

Then, change main.py:

```
from lib.foo import hello_world

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello_world()
```

And foo.py:

```
from bar import name

def hello_world():
    print(f"Hello {name}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hello_world()
```

Answer (score -2):

Just import `bar` directly:

[image]

foo and bar are both the modules that at the same level, there's no need to back to `lib`, then to search bar. We can directly run `from bar import name`.

More detailed information please refer to [Python Docs - The import System](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html?highlight=import)